# what are the firewall/DNS requirements for SF startup

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Can't start SF and this is in the logs:

```
PS>TerminatingError(Connect-ServiceFabricCluster): "No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS issue."
```

running on local dev machine. What should I check exactly in the firewall/DNS?

Comment: did you have a look inside the trace files (C:\SfDevCluster\Log\Traces) to see if there are more details about the error?

Comment: thanks for suggestion. How do you read those files? .etl extension

Comment: I used perfview to read file - thanks